# How to pass switch statement as function argument in Javascript ES6?

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux

How do you pass a switch statement as a function argument in Javascript?

I want to do this with Redux library:

```
const agendaPointsReducer = function (state = initialState, action) {
  return Object.assign({}, state, switch (action.type) {
    case OPEN_AGENDA_POINT: {
      state.modal_is_open = true,
      state.point_id = action.id
    }
    case CLOSE_AGENDA_POINT: {
      state.modal_is_open = false
    }
  })
}
```

But I get an unexpected token error. I know this could be possible in Coffeescript, is there a way to do this in Javascript es6?

Comment: What do you mean? How?

Comment: What is the point of passing a side effect as a function argument? Even if `switch` statements were expressions, the one in the example would  result in `undefined`

Comment: You can't pass a switch statement.  You have to wrap it in a function.  But, `Object.assign()` is expecting you to pass it an object with properties that it will copy.  So, you have to pass an object there.

Comment: Has your question been answered now?  If so, please select the best answer and click the green checkmark next to it to indicate to the community that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you might really want to do is something like this:

```
const agendaPointsReducer = function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case OPEN_AGENDA_POINT: {
      return {
        ...state,
        modal_is_open: true,
        point_id: action.id
      };
    }
    case CLOSE_AGENDA_POINT: {
      return {
        ...state,
        modal_is_open: false,
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This does work, but after some sytax error correction.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to wrap it into a function like this:

```
const agendaPointsReducer = function (state = initialState, action) {
  return Object.assign({}, state, (() => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case OPEN_AGENDA_POINT: {
        state.modal_is_open = true,
        state.point_id = action.id
      }
      case CLOSE_AGENDA_POINT: {
        state.modal_is_open = false
      }
    }
  })())
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting, will try this out

Comment: I think a `return` statement is needed before each object!

Comment: Just used the original code where no `break` or `return` were given.

Comment: Plus, there is no need for passing the parametter `state` it's already defined inside the anonymous function!

Comment: Uhhh, `Object.assign()` is expecting an object with properties and the properties will be copied.  It would be a lot clearer to just create the desired object BEFORE you call `Object.assign()` and then just pass that object.  This is really hard to follow code (if it even works).

Comment: you're completely right. i think it should be working, but it is really hard to get.

Comment: I still don't see how this can possibly be the right way to do this.  You are modifying the `state` object which is a side-effect.  You are passing `undefined` to `Object.assign()` as the third argument which is just wrong.  It might accidentally work because of the side effect, but it's certainly not the right way to do things.

Comment: Can someone provide an example with correct code and correct redux state handling? @jfriend00

Answer (score 2):

`switch` statements are not expressions in Javascript. In Coffeescript, everything is an expression (a la Ruby). Due to this, there is not a way to do this. Further, in the example you have just shown, there is no reason to, as your `switch` statement is just modifying the `state` variable which is already being passed.

Answer (score 1):

So, `Object.assign()` copies properties from the objects you pass it onto the destination object.  So, what you need to pass it is objects with properties that it can copy from.

If what you're trying to do is to create an object that has a property based on the current execution of a switch statement (which is my guess for what you're trying to do), then I'd suggest you just create the source object before calling `Object.assign()` and pass that object to it.

Doing it the way I show here will avoid any side effects that would change the passed in object too (that's why we set the properties in the switch statement on a local object, not on the `state` object):

```
const agendaPointsReducer = function (state = initialState, action) {
    let srcObj = {};
    switch (action.type) {
        case OPEN_AGENDA_POINT:
            srcObj.modal_is_open = true;
            srcObj.point_id = action.id;
            break;
        case CLOSE_AGENDA_POINT:
            srcObj.modal_is_open = false;
            break;
    }

    return Object.assign({}, state, srcObj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the given answers specific to your question I want to provide you a more general answer.

To pass a `switch` statement to a function you need to transform it into an expression. There are two distinct ways to achieve this.

### Wrap `switch` in a function

```js
const apply = f => x => f(x);

const enumerate = apply(x => {
  switch (x.constructor) {
    case Number: {
      return inc(x);
    }

    case String: {
      return succ(x);
    }

    default: throw TypeError();
  }
});

const inc = x => x + 1;

const succ = x => String.fromCharCode(x.charCodeAt(0) + 1);

console.log("enum 1:", enumerate(1)); // 2

console.log("enum a:", enumerate("a")); // "b"
```

With this approach I use `apply` as a little auxiliary function. It makes the calling code more readable, e.g. `Object.assign({}, state, apply(x => {/* switch statement */}) (action.type))`

### Express `switch` itself as a function

```js
const caseOf = (...pairs) => x => {
  let g;

  pairs.some(([guard, f], i) => guard(x) 
   ? (g = f, true)
   : false);

  return g(x);
}

const inc = x => x + 1;

const succ = x => String.fromCharCode(x.charCodeAt(0) + 1);

const enumerate = caseOf(
  [x => x.constructor === Number, x => x + 1],
  [x => x.constructor === String, x => String.fromCharCode(x.charCodeAt(0) + 1)]
);

console.log("enum 1:", enumerate(1));

console.log("enum a:", enumerate("a"));
```

`caseOf` is a normal function, a higher order function to be more precise. You can apply it wherever an expression is allowed.

### Destructuring assignment

Destructuring assignment is an non-obvious advantage that both approaches have over normal `switch` statements. You can apply destructuring assignment without additional variables:

```js
const apply = f => x => f(x);

const sqr = x => x * x

const xs = [2],
 ys = [];

console.log(
  sqr(apply(([x]) => { // <= destructuring assignment
    switch (x) {
      case undefined: return 0;
      default: return x;
    }
  }) (xs))
);

console.log(
  sqr(apply(([x]) => { // <= destructuring assignment
    switch (x) {
      case undefined: return 0;
      default: return x;
    }
  }) (ys))
);
```

```js
const caseOf = (...pairs) => x => {
  let g;

  pairs.some(([guard, f], i) => guard(x) 
   ? (g = f, true)
   : false);

  return g(x);
}

const sqr = x => x * x;

const isAssigned = x => x !== undefined && x !== null;

const always = x => _ => x;

const xs = [5],
 ys = [];
 
console.log(
  caseOf(
    [([x]) => isAssigned(x), sqr], // <= destructuring assignment
    [always(true), always(0)] // default case
  ) (xs)
);

console.log(
  caseOf(
    [([x]) => isAssigned(x), sqr], // <= destructuring assignment
    [always(true), always(0)] // default case
  ) (ys)
);
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answers given by [daniel_franz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42475160/3297291) and [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42475310/3297291) are the best and most straightforward solutions. But it's still fun to think about alternatives :)

I had some fun experimenting with trying to store `switch` logic in a `Map`. It probably has many downsides (for one, you can't chain cases by omitting a `break`), and it makes stuff overly complicated, so I guess we'll have to look at it as just an exploration and not as a "this is how I would do it in a real project"...

**The approach:**

- Create a `Map` with for each `case`, an entry
- Each entry has the `case` as a key
- Each entry has a *function that returns the desired result* as a value
- For undefined cases, `Map`'s `getItem` returns `null`, which we'll wrap in a function as well

**The code:**

```js
const apply = f => typeof f === "function" ? f() : null;
const Switch = (input, ...entries) => apply(new Map(entries).get(input));

const types = {
  INCREMENT: "INCREMENT",
  DECREMENT: "DECREMENT",
  SQUARE: "SQUARE"
};


const myNumberReducer = function(state = { myNumber: 0 }, action = {}) {
  return Object.assign({}, state, Switch(action.type,
    [ types.INCREMENT, () => ({ myNumber: state.myNumber + 1 }) ],
    [ types.DECREMENT, () => ({ myNumber: state.myNumber - 1 }) ],
    [ types.SQUARE,    () => ({ myNumber: state.myNumber * state.myNumber }) ]
  ));
}


let lastState = myNumberReducer();
console.log(lastState); // myNumber: 0

lastState = myNumberReducer(lastState, { type: types.INCREMENT });
console.log(lastState); // myNumber: 1

lastState = myNumberReducer(lastState, { type: types.INCREMENT });
lastState = myNumberReducer(lastState, { type: types.SQUARE });
console.log(lastState); // myNumber: 4
```