# What do the curly braces do in switch statement after case in es6?

Tags: javascript, scope, ecmascript-6, switch-statement

What's the difference between:

```
switch (expression) {
    case:
      somethings;
      break;
}
```

and

```
switch (expression) {
    case: {
      somethings;
      break;
    }
}
```

At first I thought that I could return an object literal like so, but it turns out it's a syntax error. What's the difference actually?

Example from another question:
[How to pass switch statement as function argument in Javascript ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475118/how-to-pass-switch-statement-as-function-argument-in-javascript-es6/42475344#42475344)

Comment: Syntax on both of those are invalid. Case should specify something to match on and returning requires the `return` keyword.

Comment: Why do you have break statements in arrays in your example? Please give a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Example provided. Break statments were meant as optional, as in MDN

Comment: Can you explain a downvote?

Comment: Someone should be able to hit f12 and copy/paste your example into chrome console. Try it.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Curly braces used in this way establish their own block scope, in which you can define local `let` variables or `const` constants:

```js
switch (false) {
    case true: {
      let x = "bar";
      console.log(x);
      break;
    }

    case false: {
      let x = "baz";
      console.log(x);
      break;
    }
}
```

The example would throw without nested block scopes, since multiple `let`/`const` declarations with the same identifier are not allowed within the same scope in Ecmascript 2015.

Please note that the `switch` statement creates a block scope itself, i.e. whether you use nested block scopes or not, `let`/`const` declarations inside `switch` don't leak into the parent scope.

However, in the context of `switch`, curly brackets are also used purely decorative, to visually highlight the blocks of the individual `case` branches.

Comment: _"They highlight the block of each case visually"_ That would be decoration, not syntactic sugar. _"this isn't really necessary in most cases"_ It would be more useful to describe when it **is** necessary.

Comment: Hm, is there a strict definition of syntactic sugar?

Comment: syntactic sugar = simpler syntax. Adding braces is not exactly simpler ;) _"If you don't terminate cases with break, different let/const variables within cases might interfere with each other"_ It's one scope, so two declarations with the same identifier will throw an error, `break` or not.

Comment: @zeroflagL Your second statement is definitely right. You caught me! Anyway, which syntax is simpler is highly opinion based, so I leave it at syntactic sugar. You offer an alternative term in your comment, so people can choose their favorite one.

Comment: That's a good point. I would say that optional braces here fall into the same category as in  if/else if/else.

Comment: _"which syntax is simpler is highly opinion based"_ That's not the point. Take `a ** b` instead of `Math.pow(a,b)`. Both mean the same, but one is shorter / more concise. That's syntactic sugar. But `case 1: let x = 2` and `case 1: { let x = 2 } are completely different in their outcome. It's not just different syntax, it **is** different. An apple is not syntactic sugar for an orange.

Comment: @zeroflagL I updated my answer according to your comments, so your effort was hopefully not in vain.

Comment: @zeroflagL if there are different runtimes associated with the two calls, I'm not sure I would label it as syntactic sugar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41679191/why-is-math-pow-sometimes-not-equal-to-in-javascript

Comment: @cchamberlain An spec-compliant engine runs the same operation.

Answer (score 8):

you have to use curly brackets:

1. when creating **more** block scoped variables (`const` / `let`) with **the same name**

   - according to spec [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#Block-scope_variables_within_switch_statements)
   - ERROR: Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'variablename' has already been declared
2. when using **eslint** in default settings and using **even single one** (`const` / `let`)

   - according to rule [no-case-declarations](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-case-declarations)
   - ERROR: Unexpected lexical declaration in case block no-case-declarations