# Multiple i"if" values?

Tags: javascript

I have made my first js script and I was wondering, is it possible to add multiple values to a "if var =="

```
var day = window.prompt("How was your day? Describe it in 1 word!");

if (day == null, "bad", "terrible") {
    document.write("How come?");
} else {
    document.write("sounds great");
}
```

I expect it to give a different response ONLY if the var day is bad or terrible. Not for any other responses!

But the output is only

Comment: either ad multiple condition or use `in_array`

Comment: Thanks alot! It's my first time working with js so thank you for the quick response!

Comment: @DevsiOdedra there is no "in_array" in javascript. He can either use `indexOf` or `includes` in his case (or eventually `any`). `in_array` exists in php, not in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (day == null || day == "bad" || day == "terrible") {
    document.write("How come?");
} else {
    document.write("sounds great");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement.

```
switch (day) {
  case "bad":
  case "terrible":{ document.write("How come?"); } break;
  default: { document.write("sounds great"); } break;
}
```

So, in you case:

```js
var day = window.prompt("How was your day? Describe it in 1 word!");
switch (day) {
   case "bad":
   case "terrible":{ document.write("How come?"); } break;
   default: { document.write("sounds great"); } break;
}
```

Comment: why the block statment in `case` statements part?

Comment: 'cause I suppose he won't write just one line code.

Comment: [What do the curly braces do in switch statement after case in es6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480949/what-do-the-curly-braces-do-in-switch-statement-after-case-in-es6) I've always used it, I don't know if its a good practice, this could be a great question.

Comment: @Alessandro no, it won't be a great question. It's primarily opinion based and should be closed as such.

Comment: @VLAZ, it is not opion based, it is in this case superfluous, because of no local variables.

Comment: @NinaScholz coding styles might prefer it even if superfluous, however. Yes, it's *pointless* but since it is, you are free to require it as there won't be any change in behaviour. Coding style is all about that - requiring one of multiple options when there is no functional difference. And coding styles are just opinions, ergo, if a coding style would make you choose something, it's POB.

Comment: @NinaScholz I always close my code into braces, even when it's just one line, I think it's cleaner, especially because you can add new lines without lose scope variables and it's better to read code versioning diff.